# Moving textured pipe along path

Tags: modeling, animation, bezier-curves, path

i need to animate a cable being moved trough a machine, ive tested ways to do this with the curve/bevel and playing with the start/stop of this, problem comes when i have a texture on it as this ends up deforming when moved around a bend, which it needs to do, not to mention moving the start/stop of the curve doesnt actually give the illusion of moving unless you see the ends of it, so close ups just end up looking like a stationary tube.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your current setup and the texture distortion? It does sound like a problem with reality, like, in real life it's sometime hard to tell if something smooth is moving unless there's irregularities on it. Maybe adding ring/stripes to the cable would help?

Comment: i have rings on it, just with the current setup i had it showed a lot of distortion on the rings when it came to a bend, it seems ive gotten my answer now though thanks! (also no photos because of an NDA of sorts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a (straight) pipe modelled as a curve, using its native Bevel, mapped in its own UV space, deformed along its X by another spiral curve, using a *Curve* modifier. Translating the pipe along X with respect to the spiral's origin moves it around the spiral.

[image]

That's a lot of curves :) the straight pipe could have been a mesh.

[image]

Comment: wow this really seems like what i was after! I still consider myself very much a newbie still in blender so this is awesome to learn, thank you!

Comment: The _"Master of illustration"_ strikes again.

Comment: @ batFINGER Thank you. Yes, I like this one. I should go back and read my Edward R. Tufte .. especially _The Visual Display of Quantitative Information_. Give it a look, somehow, if you haven't, before. I like his rule of thumb for factual illustration.. you should imagine that ink is very, very expensive.